# Swift linker error in release build fixable by adding code

Tags: swift, linker, linker-errors, xcode8

In Xcode 8, a Swift project of mine works in Debug mode but fails to link in Release mode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.(subscript.materializeForSet : (Swift.Int) -> A).(closure #1)"
```

I can fix the error by changing this line:

```
let nextPeriod = currentSchedule.periods.filter({ $0.startDate > now }).sorted(by: { $0.startDate < $1.startDate }).first
```

to:

```
let nextPeriod = currentSchedule.periods.filter({ $0.startDate > now }).first
```

but that obviously alters the behavior of my app. Luckily, I can also fix the error by adding the following line to almost any method, initializer, or property observer:

```
let _ = [""].sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
```

(I say "almost" any because it doesn't seem to fix the linker error when added to property observers on properties with `enum` types I defined myself.)

...What?

Comment: Are you using one of the beta releases of Xcode 8?

Comment: @Cristik: GM seed now, but was happening in the last beta too. Not sure before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler bug, which has been fixed in `Xcode 8.1`.

Comment: Seems to work in Xcode 8.1 indeed! I couldn't find any mention of it in the release notes, though--have you seen anything about it?

Comment: No. I ran into the same issue and updating Xcode cured the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using `sorted(by:` method in one project that I was migrating to Swift 3.
It seems a bug in the compiler and I found this following references:

- [Swift 2.1 Error sorting in place, only on release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444460/swift-2-1-error-sorting-in-place-only-on-release-builds/33614211) (same problem in an old Xcode/Swift version)
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63213 (problem on Xcode 8)

For now the only workaround that worked for me was change the swift compiler optimization level to `None` on Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

At first i thought is that weird code apple inserted in few places with Comparable stuffs... But didn't worked when i added it back. What worked was to step down the optimization level to: fast, single file optimization
They messed up this xcode version, storyboards also have huge problems.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when migrating to Swift 3.

I got it to work by letting the object that calls the code inherit from NSObject.