# Liker errors in release build - function signature specialization <Arg[2] = Exploded>

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

This code build fine in `Debug` mode (Xcode8.0):

```
private func rebuildMyClass3sForMyClassCache() {
    someWorker.fetchClass1Categories { (categories: [MyClass2]) in
        self.representedMyClass3sForMyClass1 = categories
            .flatMap { $0.class1s.sorted(by: { (a: MyClass1, b: MyClass1) -> Bool in
                return (a.priorityWithinCategory ?? 0) < (b.priorityWithinCategory ?? 0)
            })
    }
            // we want to show MyClass1 sections only for MyClass1s that actually contain MyClass3s
    .filter { $0.belongingMyClass3s.count > 0 }
}
```

but gives linker errors when in building `Release`:

```
Showing Recent Issues   "Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.(subscript.materializeForSet : (Swift.Int) -> A).(closure #1)", referenced from:

function signature specialization <Arg[2] = Exploded> of generic specialization
<Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<MessagesExtension.MyClass1> with
Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<MessagesExtension.MyClass1> :
Swift.MutableCollection in Swift and
Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<MessagesExtension.MyClass1> :
Swift.RandomAccessCollection in Swift> of Swift._siftDown <A where A:
Swift.MutableCollection, A: Swift.RandomAccessCollection> (inout A, index : A.Index, subRange : Swift.Range<A.Index>, by : inout (A.Iterator.Element, A.Iterator.Element) -> Swift.Bool) -> () in ManageMyClass3sInteractor.o
```

[this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381045/swift-linker-error-in-release-build-fixable-by-adding-code) suggests to disable compiler optimizations, which
   is not an option for Release in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Xcode 8.0 bug.

Updating to Xcode 8.1 fixes the issue.